# Youtube Data API Project in a JAR File

Tags: java, eclipse, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

I built a java program that is based on the Youtube Data API command line Examples. The program works fine and I now tried to convert the java class into a JAR file in order for me not having to start eclipse each time I want to use the program. To build the jar file I used the Eclipse export function "File->Export->Java->runnable JAR file". 
I also chose to extract all required Libraries into the generated JAR.

All seems to work fine up to the point where I execute the program, which even creates the output file I wanted it to create but the JAR file doesn't seem to be able to retrieve data from the Youtube Data API, which means the created file is empty.

Is there anyone who can help me or at least is experiencing silimar issues?

Below I attached two sample Outputs:

This is what I get when executing the code within eclipse which gives me the correct answer

```
Channel; Subscribercount

Channelname; 12345
```

This is what I get when executing the JAR file

```
Channel; Subscribercount

Channelname; null
```

It seems that the JAR fails to connect to the API

Here I have a console log: 
None of these errors occur when executing within eclipse

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth.authorize(Auth.java:51)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.getChannelsVideos.retrieveChannelInfo(getChannelsVideos.java:220)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.getChannelsVideos.main(getChannelsVideos.java:49)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth.authorize(Auth.java:51)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.getChannelsVideos.getChannelsVideo(getChannelsVideos.java:92)
        at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.getChannelsVideos.main(getChannelsVideos.java:50)
```

Comment: Question is unclear about the errors you have. try adding print/log statements in the code which helps you to troubleshoot.

Comment: @suman jakkula I added a console log and some further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:I copied the client_secrets.json and the youtube. properties into the same folder as the JAR. Obviously it wasn't possible to import these files from within the JAR structure